# c# / xaml trouble (Microsoft Silverlight)

Tags: c#, xaml, silverlight, visual-studio-2015

I am currently creating an online file storage system using Microsoft Silverlight. However, I am running into some trouble. when the site loads, I want there to be buttons/links to every file that the user has in their directory, but I am unable to create buttons on the c# side, and can't use any sort of OOP to create a variable number of buttons in XAML. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Silverlight has been deprecated for years now. I wouldn't use it if I were you.

Answer (score 0):

Scott Guthrie wrote a tutorial on using the `ListBox` and `DataBinding` to display list data.
https://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/silverlight-tutorial-part-5-using-the-listbox-and-databinding-to-display-list-data

[image]

Just add a `<Button />` in the `StackPanel`.